# CSS block elements with relative width?

Tags: css, block

Here's what I'm trying to pull off...

[image]

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<article>
  <h3>Fading Forest</h3>
  <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
  <p class="permalink"><a href="http://example.com/12345" title="">example.com/12345</a></p>
</article>
```

So what I need to do is wrap each `h3` and `p` in a box, but right now, since the `h3` and `p` tags are block level elements, the corresponding blocks just extend the full width.

I want the width to adjust according to the content (and just apply `max-width` so they don't extend too wide).

This is what I've got so far, though it doesn't work...obviously. http://jsfiddle.net/hAtRs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the `inline-block`; it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Float and clear to the left:

```css
h3, p {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAtRs/20/

Comment: Make sure to make the article element fully wrap around the floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h3, p {
    background:#999;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 80px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then add line breaks after every element.